# Init django server with start-stop-daemon like a service

Tags: python, django, linux

I'm trying to init a virtualenv and runserver command of django project on Ubuntu 16 Linux

I create a file on `/etc/init.d/initfile` with the commands to start and stop service:

```
do_start()
{
    echo -n "Starting " $NAME " ..."

    if [ -f $PIDFILE ]
    then 
        echo "\n-> Service " $NAME " is running."
    else
        start-stop-daemon --start --background --quiet --name $NAME --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --exec $DAEMON
        echo "\n-> Service " $NAME " started..."
    fi
}
```

and the `$DAEMON` is a file with:

```
VIRTUALENV_DIR=/home/user/python/DjangoProjects/newEnv1
SITE_DIR=/home/user/python/DjangoProjects/newEnv1/sampleSite


source $VIRTUALENV_DIR/bin/activate
python $SITE_DIR/manage.py runserver 0:8080
```

but when I check the process with `ps -fu root` is generated 3 pid id: 22875, 22878 and 22880

[Image with multiple pid ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPP6C.png)

the problem is, when I execute the stop command only stopped the pid id that include in $PIDFILE but the other is running yet so the server still running.

Can you help me please ? thanks